# Thread runs function only once, and only returns value once? How to continuously return function value?

Tags: python, multithreading, sensors, nonblocking

I have a function that reads data from an IR thermal camera, processes the data and returns a value.  In the code below it returns the minimum temperature detected.  This function is computationally intense so I want to run it in a separate thread.

In the example below, I have a class that starts the thread.  This works once.  It reads the sensor and returns the temp.  But it never runs the function again.  It keeps returning the same temp value, even if I change the input to the sensor. The function works fine on its own in a separate program and continuously updates temps.

I want the function to run in a thread because I am also playing sounds and controlling LEDs.

How to I get the function to run multiple times in the thread so I can continuously or periodically get the temp values in the main thread?

I tried using a thread class but I must be doing something wrong.  I also tried using a queue but never got any data to return.

```
import queue
import sys
import pygame
import cv2
import random
import math
import colorsys
import time
from rpi_ws281x import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import threading

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/pi/irpython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5")
import MLX90640 as mlx

# IR Function

def irCounter():
  while True:  
        img = Image.new( 'L', (24,32), "black") # make IR image

        mlx.setup(8) #set frame rate of MLX90640

        f = mlx.get_frame()

        mlx.cleanup()     

        for x in range(24):
            row = []
            for y in range(32):
                val = f[32 * (23-x) + y]
                row.append(val)
                img.putpixel((x, y), (int(val)))

        # convert raw temp data to numpy array
        imgIR = np.array(img)

        ## Threshold the -40C to 300 C temps to a more human range
        # Sensor seems to read a bit cold, calibrate in final setting
        rangeMin = 6 # low threshold temp in C
        rangeMax = 20 # high threshold temp in C

        # Apply thresholds based on min and max ranges
        depth_scale_factor = 255.0 / (rangeMax-rangeMin)
        depth_scale_beta_factor = -rangeMin*255.0/(rangeMax-rangeMin)

        depth_uint8 = imgIR*depth_scale_factor+depth_scale_beta_factor
        depth_uint8[depth_uint8>255] = 255
        depth_uint8[depth_uint8<0] = 0
        depth_uint8 = depth_uint8.astype('uint8')

        # increase the 24x32 px image to 240x320px for ease of seeing
        bigIR = cv2.resize(depth_uint8, dsize=(240,320), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        # Normalize the image
        normIR = cv2.normalize(bigIR, bigIR, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)

        # Use a bilateral filter to blur while hopefully retaining edges
        brightBlurIR = cv2.bilateralFilter(normIR,9,150,150)

        # Threshold the image to black and white 
        retval, threshIR = cv2.threshold(brightBlurIR, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        # Define kernal for erosion and dilation and closing operations
        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

        erosionIR = cv2.erode(threshIR,kernel,iterations = 1)

        dilationIR = cv2.dilate(erosionIR,kernel,iterations = 1)

        closingIR = cv2.morphologyEx(dilationIR, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        # Detect countours
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closingIR, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

        # Get the number of contours ( contours count when touching edge of image while blobs don't)
        #ncontours = str(len(contours))
        ncontours = max(f)

        # Show images in window during testing
        #cv2.imshow("Combined", closingIR)

        return ncontours
        cv2.waitKey(1)

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(30)
print("pygame initialized")

# assign sound chennels for pygame
channel0 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)
channel3 = pygame.mixer.Channel(3)
channel4 = pygame.mixer.Channel(4)


# load soundfiles
echoballs = pygame.mixer.Sound("echo balls bounce.ogg")
organbounce = pygame.mixer.Sound("ORGAN BOUNCE.ogg")
jar = pygame.mixer.Sound("jar.ogg")
garland = pygame.mixer.Sound("GARLAND.ogg")
dribble= pygame.mixer.Sound("dribble.ogg")

# initializing sounds list  
soundsList = [echoballs, organbounce, jar, garland, dribble]
# use random.sample() to shuffle sounds list 
shuffledSounds = random.sample(soundsList, len(soundsList))

IRcount = 0 # for testing only

pygame.display.set_mode((32, 8)) # need display for keyboard input

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 256      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
#LED_PIN        = 10     # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (10 uses SPI /dev/spidev0.0).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 100     # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

# Define functions which animate LEDs in various ways.
plasmaTime = 0.0 # time
plasmaSpeed = 0.5 # speed of time

def sineLED1 ():
    h = 8
    w = 32
    out = [ Color( 0, 0, 0 ) for x in range( h * w ) ]
    plasmaBright = 100.0
    for x in range( h ):
        for y in range( w ):
            hue = ((128+(128*math.sin(y + plasmaTime/ 8))))/256
            hsv = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(.5, 1,hue )
            if y % 2 == 0: #even
                out[ x + (h * y)] = Color( *[ int( round( c * plasmaBright ) ) for c in hsv ] )
            else: #odd
                out[ (y * h) + (h -1 -x) ] = Color( *[ int( round( c * plasmaBright ) ) for c in hsv ] )
    for i in range( 0, strip.numPixels(), 1 ):# iterate over all LEDs - range(start_value, end_value, step)
        strip.setPixelColor(i, out[ i ]) # set pixel to color in picture
    strip.show()


# Threading class to get temp from IR function
class TempTask:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ir_temp = 0
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_temp)

    def update_temp(self):
        self.ir_temp = irCounter()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # start thread
    task = TempTask()
    task.start()

    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
    # Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
    strip.begin()

    print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

    try:
        while True:
            #simulate increase / decreat of people count from IRsensor for testing until irCounter function non-blocking
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        IRcount -= 1
                        print(IRcount)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        IRcount += 1
                        print(IRcount)
                break
            if IRcount == 0:
                print(task.ir_temp) # print temp from sensor, only prints first time function runs
                sineLED1()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_busy() == False: channel0.play(shuffledSounds[0],loops = -1)     
            elif IRcount == 1:
                sineLED1()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(1).get_busy() == False: channel1.play(shuffledSounds[1],loops = -1)
            elif IRcount == 2:
                sineLED1()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(2).get_busy() == False: channel2.play(shuffledSounds[2],loops = -1)
            elif IRcount == 3:
                sineLED1()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(3).get_busy() == False: channel3.play(shuffledSounds[3],loops = -1)
            elif IRcount == 4:
                sineLED1()
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(4).get_busy() == False: channel4.play(shuffledSounds[4],loops = -1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       colorWipe(strip, Color(0,0,0), 1)
       pygame.mixer.stop()
```

I have searched the forums and tried many things but am at a loss as what to try next.

Here is the snippet from the full code above where I make the thread class and start the thread

```
class TempTask:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ir_temp = 0
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_temp)

    def update_temp(self):
        self.ir_temp = irCounter()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # start thread
    task = TempTask()
    task.start()
```

Any help or suggestions of what to try next is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt you have the line `return ncontours` in your working, separate program?

Comment: Correct, I did not have that return call in the test program. In the IR thermal sensor algorithm test program, I used `cv2.imshow()` to show the image for testing.  I also printed out the min and max temps to the console.  Do you think the return is the problem?

Comment: Yes, the `return` statement breaks out of your while loop, leaving the thread with nothing to do.

Comment: @JohanL I made a new test program in isolation with the `return ncontours` and it works unthreaded and continuously sends back new temp data. If the return breaks out, how do I send the temp information back to the main thread?  I tried to use a queue before but never got it to work.

Comment: That sounds strange. How does that program look? Are you calling the function repeatedly or is the `return` statement not in the same place?

Comment: I call the function repeatedly. The IR test program is not a threaded program.  When I combine the IR sensor algorithm with the LEDs and pygame sounds it takes to long to complete and the LEDs stutter.   That is why I am trying to run the `irCounter()` function in a thread.

Comment: I added a `global ncontours` before `ncontours = max(f)` in the `irCounter()` function.  Then in the main program I can print out 'print(ncontours)' and it updates the temperatures. The return was why the thread was stoping, well not stopping but not running the function anymore.   Thank you for pointing out the `return` problem.  I was trying to do it without using a global variable but this is currently working and the LEDs run full speed and sound works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to update continuously you will need to modify the `TempTask` class so its `update_temp()` method contains a loop, and also add a `Lock` to it to control concurrent access to the `ir_temp` attribute to allow it to safely be accessed by more than one thread.

Note, that it's not clear if the `Lock` is really needed, since you do nothing but read the `TempTask` instance's attribute in the main thread — but the loop in the  `update_temp()` method is needed to keep running the `irCounter()` function. You also might want to change the `while True:` to reference another (additional) instance attribute that control whether it is to keep running or not.

Additional note:

It's unclear why you have the `while True:` loop in `irCounter()`, because it has as `return` near the end that prevents it from ever iterating more than once. Doing so isn't crucial, but I recommend that you remove it.

```
class TempTask:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ir_temp = 0
        self.lock = threading.Lock()  # ADDED
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_temp)

    def update_temp(self):  # MODIFIED
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                self.ir_temp = irCounter()
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Polling delay.

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()
```

In addition to that you need to change where you read the shared attribute in the main loop (see `# ADDED` line):

```
     .
     .
     .
    try:
        while True:  # This while loop doesn't iterate - suggest removal.
            #simulate increase / decrease of people count from IRsensor for testing until irCounter function non-blocking
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        IRcount -= 1
                        print(IRcount)
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        IRcount += 1
                        print(IRcount)
                break
            if IRcount == 0:
                with task.lock:  # ADDED.
                    print(task.ir_temp) # print temp from sensor
                sineLED1()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_busy() == False: channel0.play(shuffledSounds[0],loops = -1)
            elif IRcount == 1:
                sineLED1()
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I made the changes that you suggested and it does continuously run the function `irCounter()` but it does not report back the temperature.  `print(task.ir_temp)` just prints `0`.  I know the function is working because the `imshow()` part of the code displays an updating thermal image.  Your example also seems to block the rest of the code.  The LED functions are slowed down.  I will continue to experiment with your suggestions but I may have to use the global variable since that didn't slow the program down.  Thank you again.

Comment: lukecv: I don't know why `ir_temp` doesn't appear to be updating (can't run the code myself for obvious reasons). When I wrote this I suspected `irCounter()` might block the main thread for too long. You may be able to mitigate that by adding one or more short `time.sleep()` calls to it in strategic places to give the other thread a chance to run. In Python, threads really don't run concurrently, there's something called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) that prevents it — it's more like cooperative multi-threading. If all you want to do is get a single value, try `multiprocessing` instead.

Comment: BTW, `task` (and therefore `task.ir_temp`) _is_ a global variable.

Comment: P.S. You can also try increasing the polling delay in `update_temp()` which controls how frequently `irCounter()` gets called.

Comment: `ir_temp` didn't update because I had a dumb typo `irtemp`.  It updates now but still slows down the LED part of the program.  I tried to strategically add `time.sleep()` to the `irCounter()` function but it did not help.  I also tried to make it poll lest often but it still stuttered. If i remove the `with task.lock` from the main thread it prints out the temps with `print(task.ir_temp)` and everything runs at full speed.  Since I didn't realize that `task.ir_temp` was also global I might as well do it that way.  By taking away the `with task.lock` will that cause problems?

Comment: I only need to get one value back, the calculated number of contours in the image from OpenCV that represents the ~ number of people in the room.  Now I am sending back temp data for testing.  I will also take a look at multiprocessing to see if that is a better way.  Thank you for your help.  I am going to accept your answer since it was a way to make the thread keep calling a function with a `return` in it.  That combined with @JohanL 's spot on advice about the `return` breaking out of the `while True:` loop, I have code that might not be perfect but works for the task at hand.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. If you used `multiprocessing` to run the `irCounter()` function it would likely interfere with the main process _much_ less. It not that hard to do and very similar (on purpose) to threading, and as long as you don't try to exchange large amounts or complicated data between the processes, might be a better way to do this. Threading isn't that great for computationally-bound concurrent processing because of the GIL (but `multiprocessing` is).

Comment: Here's an excellent [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk&feature=youtu.be) on concurrency by Python guru (and core developer) Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: Thank you fro the video link.  It was interesting.  I will try to use these concepts in the program.